# How to return/yield from map function

Tags: dart

Why can I do:

```
  var userArray = ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3'];
  var userList = userArray.map((user) => user).toList();
```

But in a function body nor return or yield works:

```
  var userArray = ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3'];
  var userList = userArray.map((user) => {return user}).toList();
  var userList = userArray.map((user) => {yield user}).toList();
```

Comment: `() => { ... }` creates a function that returns a `Set`, and `return`/`yield` don't make sense as initializers for `Set` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var userArray = ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3'];
  var userList = userArray.map((user) => {return user}).toList();
```

If you want to use `{}` braces, you can't use an arrow function (`=>`). Instead:

```
  var userArray = ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3'];
  var userList = userArray.map((user) {
    return user;
  }).toList();
```

(you also need the semicolon).